# Fetch host name & its type while scaning network using (NDR) Network Discovery Repository

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm trying to  fetch `Connected Device details of Network`. I have refereed Network Discovery Repository I'm able to get *IP address and Mac address(Hardware address)* but not able to `Host name` & `device type`.

I have used following code with different Stackoverflow's suggested post.I have also implement `jcifs jar`. but no luck I'm not able to fetch host name  and its type from network.

*code:*

```
1) 
NbtAddress nbtAddress = NbtAddress.getByName("Base");
InetAddress address = nbtAddress.getInetAddress();
String hostname = address.getHostAddress();

2)
InetAddress addr = NbtAddress.getByName(strIp).getInetAddress();
host.hostname =addr.getCanonicalHostName();
```

your suggestion are appreciable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 1.3.17 JCIFS it has some bug which causes it to not return the hostname. You can try to use older version of JCIFS and it will give you the host name. Older version of JCIFS (1.2.25) has other issues but depends what you use it for.